# print of echo bp_displayed_user_id in a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, buddypress

I am trying to print or echo `bp_displayed_user_id` in a shortcode.

```
echo bp_displayed_user_id();
```

inside the working function (replacing 123)

```
echo do_shortcode ( '[job-type author="123"]' );
```

The job by author `123` is displayed fine when entered like above. I cant seem to find a way to print or echo the displayed user id.

Comment: found the solution:

Comment: echo do_shortcode ( '[job-type author="'. bp_displayed_user_id() .'"]' );

Comment: tanks to Shanebp https://buddypress.org/support/topic/print-of-echo-bp_displayed_user_id-in-a-shortcode/#post-279102